# onCreate() gets called instead of onActivityResult()

Tags: android, github, github-api

So I am authenticating the user via GitHub account using OAuth from browser. But after I fire the `Intent` from `LoginActivity`, the `onResume()` gets executed before the user opens the browser, thus returning the value of `uri` equals `null`.

Here is the `LoginActivity`:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button loginButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        loginButton = findViewById(R.id.button);
        final String url = "oauth url...";
        Log.d("called","oncreate");
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("called","onclick");
                attemptLogin(url);
            }
        });
    }

    private void attemptLogin(String url){
        Log.d("called","onattempt");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, BrowserActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("URL", url);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        String code = uri.getQueryParameter("code");
        Log.d("called",code);
    }
}
```

`BrowserActivity`:

```
public class BrowserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static String CALLBACK_URL = "callback url..";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_browser);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if(intent != null){
            String url = intent.getStringExtra("URL");
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
        if(uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(CALLBACK_URL)) {
            String code = uri.getQueryParameter("code");
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("code",code);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

`LoginActivity` in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.activities.LoginActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".ui.activities.BrowserActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data
            android:host="callback"
            android:scheme="app"
            />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: It is normal. Your callback just relaunch the LoginActivity according to your manifest.

Comment: But shouldn't it execute the `onActivityResult()`? @FrançoisL.

Comment: No, you have to create a dedicated Activity to intercept the callback.

Comment: Tried doing that. But in that `onResult()` gets called before the browser even starts from `onCreate()` @FrançoisL.

Comment: "But shouldn't it execute the onActivityResult()?" -- yes, but that may occur after `onCreate()`, if your process was terminated while the browser was in the foreground. Plus, `ACTION_VIEW` does not return a result, so your code in `onActivityResult()` would seem to be useless.

Comment: @CommonsWare Made some changes in the question. Please check it out now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you start the browser with

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

this intent does not return any result. It only request the browser to show the url. So the browser does not returning any result.
However, after authentification, the browser trigger an intent and request for a new instance of LoginActivity. onCreate() is called of course

It is like **LoginActivity(#1) -> Browser -> LoginActivity(#2)**

you can call this portion of code inside onCreate() it will work:

```
Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
String code = uri.getQueryParameter("code");
Log.d("called",code);
```

But two different intents(launcher and action_view) can reach the same activity for two different purposes. You'd better create two different activities. First your usual LoginActivity and a second one (which inherit from the first) BrowserActivity wich redifine onCreate. So far, your Manifest will look like

```
<activity
android:name=".ui.activities.LoginActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
android:name=".ui.activities.BrowserActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data
        android:host="callback"
        android:scheme="app"
        />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The LoginActivity code should look like this:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button loginButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    loginButton = findViewById(R.id.button);
    final String url = "oauth url...";
    Log.d("called","oncreate");
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("called","onclick");
            attemptLogin(url);
        }
    });
}

private void attemptLogin(String url){
    Log.d("called","onattempt");

        // open the browser with url

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
}

// no onResult 

}
```

And this is the BrowserActivityCode:

```
public class BrowserActivity extends LoginActivity {

// this will be triggered after authentification
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    processIntent();
}


protected void processIntent() {
    Intent intentFromBrowser = getIntent();
    if (intentFromBrowser != null) {
        Uri uri = intentFromBrowser.getData();
    if(uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(CALLBACK_URL)) {
        String code = uri.getQueryParameter("code");
        Log.d("code value", code);
    }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Even following your approach, I facing  some issues. I have updated the question with the same. Please have a look.

Comment: Could you figure out?

Comment: May I ask if you have not passed the intent to the `BrowserActivity` from the `LoginActivity`, how are you retrieving one? You are directly calling the `ACTION_VIEW` intent.

Comment: The browser pass that intent to BrowserActivity

Comment: Cool. I didn't know that. And what if I want to send back the code to the `LoginActivity`? Please do not make changes to this answer, but paste via pastebin.com or something. Also, if I want to contact you, how may I? I am really grateful to you and might need your help in future :)

Comment: No need to redirect to LoginActivity because BrowserActivity is a subclass of LoginActivity. contact: ygunion@gmail.com

Comment: Okay. I will write to you in case of any queries. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Although, just in case, I require to send the `code` to the `LoginActivity`, for carrying further backend processes, how may I? Because I don't want to mix up `BrowserActivity` with the backend processes. Or what alternative would you suggest?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162540/discussion-between-maheryhaja-and-brijesh-shah).